# Python- not in index error (one-hot encoded)

Tags: python, numpy, index-error, numpy-indexing

I'm working on the Titanic dataset and one-hot applied to all columns. So everything 0 and 1.

However, I get the following error in train operation. I tried many things but I could not find the solution. I tried to explain the error as much as I can, I hope you can understand the problem easily. Thank you for your time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "titanic_classifier.py", line 277, in <module>
    fire.Fire()
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 138, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 468, in _Fire
    target=component.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 672, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "titanic_classifier.py", line 220, in train
    n_sample          =  nsample if nsample is not None else m['n_sample'])
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\x\source\run_train.py", line 248, in run_train
    dfXy, dfXytest   = train(model_dict, dfXy, cols, post_process_fun)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\x\source\run_train.py", line 125, in train
    data_pars['train'] = {'Xtrain' : dfX[colsX].iloc[:itrain, :],
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2908, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1254, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1304, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['space_svd_0', 'interaction_svd_1', 'transit_svd_0', 'summary_svd_1', 'last_scraped_month', 'neighborhood_overview_svd_0', 'host_name_svd_0', 'house_rules_svd_1', 'house_rules_svd_0', 'first_review_month', 'transit_svd_1', 'last_review_year', 'interaction_svd_0', 'first_review_day', 'last_scraped_day', 'summary_svd_0', 'access_svd_1', 'first_review_year', 'notes_svd_0', 'name_svd_1', 'space_svd_1', 'neighborhood_overview_svd_1', 'host_since_year', 'amenities_svd_1', 'amenities_svd_0', 'host_about_svd_0', 'host_name_svd_1', 'notes_svd_1', 'name_svd_0', 'last_review_day', 'last_scraped_year', 'description_svd_0', 'host_since_day', 'last_review_month', 'access_svd_0', 'host_about_svd_1', 'host_since_month', 'description_svd_1'] not in index"
```

The part of the code where the error came from run_train.py:

```
data_pars['train'] = {'Xtrain' : dfX[colsX].iloc[:itrain, :],
                          'ytrain' : dfX[coly].iloc[:itrain],
                          'Xtest'  : dfX[colsX].iloc[itrain:ival, :],
                          'ytest'  : dfX[coly].iloc[itrain:ival],

                          'Xval'   : dfX[colsX].iloc[ival:, :],
                          'yval'   : dfX[coly].iloc[ival:]
                          }
```

Comment: What are `coly`, `colsX`, variables in your example? What sort of values are they holding?

Comment: It is hard to tell without the rest of the code, but the traceback implies that you passed a string rather than a list to one of your .loc or .iloc calls.

I would use pythons built in type() function and make sure colsX, itrain, coly, and ival are not strings (and are lists or integers as you expect, rather).

Comment: coly is the independent variable of the titanic dataset and colsX is the dependent variables of the titanic dataset. And all columns are one-hot encoded, so 1 and 0. @skuzzy

Comment: Thank you @mgd I checked and coly (Survived) type is str. But I did not understand why because it has only 1 and 0 values. Unfortunately, I cannot add all code because it connected many different scripts. I really tried to find where the problem comes but could not find it. Do you have any suggestions?